# Pasar por parámetro de una url una palabra con "ñ"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una función login, a la cual si le paso una password que contenga una letra ñ, por ejemplo contraseña me codifica la ñ a con su consiguiente error en el login.

```
Request URL: http://localhost/login?username=p@.com&password=contrase%C3%B1a
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
  const login = () => {

fetch(
    `${urlBack}/login?username=${username}&password=${password}`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }
)

  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data))
    router.push('/')
  })
```

}

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Mmmmm... ¿Método **POST** con parámetros en la URL?

Comment: Si lo estas haciendo para una clase, no hay problema, pero si lo estas haciendo para un trabajo -> **NUNCA JAMAS DE LOS JAMASES CONTRASEÑA EN CLARO Y MENOS EN URL**

Answer (score 2):

La manera más fácil de trabajar con `fetch` es usar un objeto `URL`:

```javascript
  const login = () => {
    
    const url = new URL(`${urlBack}/login`);
    url.searchParams.set('username', username);
    url.searchParams.set('password', password);
    
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }
    ).then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data))
        router.push('/')
      })
    
  }
```

Pero, como te han comentado, realmente yo evitaría mandar esa información como parte de la url, podrías mandarla en el body de la petición.

El motivo principal es por seguridad: incluso asumiendo que la petición va por HTTPS y nadie entre el cliente y el servidor sea capaz de descifrar la petición, la mayoría de los servidores web suelen escribir en sus logs las URL de las peticiones recibidas, con lo que cualquiera con acceso a la máquina podría ver todas las contraseñas:

```javascript
fetch(`${urlBack}/login`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({username,password})
}).then(...)
```